# How to make a slot with v-for loop Vue js 3?

Tags: vue.js, v-for, vue-props, vuejs-slots

I'm expecting to make a v-for loop with slot in a child component. How can I pass the data looped to the child component ? The data uses a table html template.

```js
// parent component

<template v-slot:delaysBody="{ delaysBody }">
  <div v-for="d in delayBody" :key="d.id">
    <td>{{delaysBody.reason}}</td>
  </div>
</template>

delaysBody: [
{
  id: '1',
  reason: 'text'
},
{
  id: '2',
  reason: 'text'
}

//child component

<tr v-for="delay in body" :key="delay.id">
  <td scope="col">{{delay.id}}</td>
  <td scope="col">{{delay.id}}</td>
  <slot name="reasonBody" v-bind:delaysBody="delaysBody"></slot>
</tr>

props: ['body']


// I had read this approach chould work, but it doesn't

<template v-for="(reasonBody, index) of Object.keys($slots)" :key="index" v-slot:[reasonBody]>
  <td scope="col"></td>
</template>
//
```

Comment: It's not immediately obvious what you want to achieve.
You want to add one delay per column?
Why do you have two delay.id in the child component?
You don't even reference the child component in the parent.

e.g. <ChildComponent />

Comment: read this: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots

Answer (score 0):

```js
delaysBody: [{
  id: '1',
  reason: 'text'
}, {
  id: '2',
  reason: 'text'
}]
```

Parent component template

```js
<ChildComponent>
  <template #delays-body="{ delaysBody }">
    <td v-for="d in delaysBody" :key="d.id">{{d.reason}}</td>
  </template>
</ChildComponent>
```

Child

```js
<tr v-for="delay in body" :key="delay.id">
  <td scope="col">{{delay.id}}</td>
  <slot name="delays-body" :delaysBody="delaysBody"></slot>
</tr>
```

Your variable names aren't making things clearer. You should reconsider the naming.

Comment: That's odd but this doesn't work, seem tobe that the naming is correct though

Comment: // Parent                              <template #delays-body="{ delaysBody }">
      <td scope="col" v-for="d in delaysBody" :key="d.id">{{d.reason}}</td>
    </template>

Comment: / /Child                                                                                                                     
   <slot name="delays-body" :delaysBody="delaysBody"></slot>

Comment: Tried vue devtools? Whet errors do you get...?
Can you provide a bit more code?

Comment: I think this slot non debuggerable